# How to make psvita browser full screen？

Tags: javascript, html5-fullscreen

I want to write a html page make my psvita browser full screen,and the JavaScript API like `requestFullscreen()`,`mozRequestFullScreen()`,`msRequestFullscreen()`,`webkitRequestFullScreen()` don't work.

This is the html:

`<button onclick="launchFullscreen(document.documentElement)">FullScreen</button>`

This is the JavaScript:

```
function launchFullscreen(element) {
  if(element.requestFullscreen) {
    element.requestFullscreen();
  } else if(element.mozRequestFullScreen) {
    element.mozRequestFullScreen();
  } else if(element.msRequestFullscreen){
    element.msRequestFullscreen();
  } else if(element.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
    element.webkitRequestFullScreen();
  }
}
```

Comment: You're assuming it's possible in the first place...